# Are there any good iPad games for kids to learn numbers?

Tags: ipad, software-recommendation, games, children

I'm looking for iPad games for my 4 year old daughter to learn numbers. I've tried many different games, like "Learn Numbers", "Counting101", "Animals Count", "Baby Phone", etc. but none of them are really good. They are either too simple, too hard or too boring.

I'm looking for something that is interactive, fun, and that my daughter can play by herself without asking me what the questions are (some games have questions written but not spoken out loud). She has learned all of the single digit numbers although sometimes she makes random mistakes with them. She doesn't know about two-digit numbers except 10, 11 and 12. If there is a game with princesses it would be perfect for her :)

Could someone here please let me know, what is a good game to try out? If possible, please describe why you think it's good.

Many thanks.

EDIT: I got the first answer for this question after my daughter has mastered numbers until 20. I think it's good for her right now. I don't try push her much at this age. So I accept Numberland since it's the first answer although it seems to be too simple at the first glance. I didn't try other apps yet but will give them a try later. Thank you all for your effort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My daughter has played with [Math Express](http://itunes.apple.com/be/artist/kidapps.com/id467953315)
No unicorn, nor Princess but a train with a lot of animals.

Comment: +1 that looks really cute. I'll definitely let my daughter try it once I get home today. Thank you very much

Comment: This app is awesome. We love it. Clean design, cute graphic, creative teaching method,etc. Thanks a lot for your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

You can try Numberland ([App Store](http://itunes.apple.com/app/numberland-hd-au-pays-des/id388154228?mt=8)). It's available in 3 languages: English, French and Spanish. It won a [Parents' Choice award](http://parents-choice.org/product.cfm?product_id=29735&StepNum=1&award=aw) in Fall 2011.

Check out the [video demo](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dvfQOg6og3g).

Comment: +1. Thanks for your suggestion. It seems to be a bit too simple though.

Answer (score 1):

Think you could turn to bestappsforkids.com, well gathers many cool games for kids, such as I got Want My lollipop and Tom's Travels from there, which are my nephew's favorite game now.

Answer (score 0):

I saw a notice of "[Math Bingo](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/math-bingo/id371338715?mt=8)" the other day.  I haven't tried it yet.  May be too advanced for your daughter?

Comment: Thanks, yes it seems to be too complicated for now. But I'll keep it in mind